# Como comprobar si existe una palabra dentro de un fichero

Tags: linux, bash, unix, centos7

Tengo el siguiente fichero en centos:

[image: fstab20190101]

Quiero que el programa me compruebe si existe "equipo" con una expresion regular como seria con el comando sed ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que no sólo quieres la palabra "equipo", sino que esté en medio de guiones y espacios como indicador.

En ese caso, una expresión regular que podrías utilizar sería:

```
^[-]+[[:space:]]equipo[[:space:]][-]+$
```

### Con sed

En el comando `sed` sería de la forma

```
$ sed -nr '/^[-]+[[:space:]]equipo[[:space:]][-]+$/p' archivo
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
```

Donde el parámetro `-n` suprime la salida del archivo antes de encontrar el patrón, y el parámetro `-r` habilita las expresiones regulares.

Aunque también puedes hacer lo mismo con otras opciones como `egrep`, `grep` o `awk` con algo del estilo.

### egrep y grep

```
$ egrep '^[-]+[[:space:]]equipo[[:space:]][-]+$' archivo 
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
```

O

```
$ grep -E '^[-]+[[:space:]]equipo[[:space:]][-]+$' archivo 
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
```

Aquí puedes hacer uso del parámetro `-q` de `grep` si lo único que se desea es "saber si existe" no sólo "saber si existe y además imprimirla en pantalla". Esto es porque el parámetro `-q` no genera una salida, sino un estado de salida de 0 —si el patrón es encontrado o incluso si hay un error— o diferente de 0 —si el patrón no es encontrado—. Esto lo puedes consultar en `grep(1)`. Ejemplo:

```
$ grep -E '^[-]+[[:space:]]equipo[[:space:]][-]+$' archivo.txt -q && echo Si existe || echo no existe
Si existe
```

### Con awk

```
$ awk '/^[-]+[[:space:]]equipo[[:space:]][-]+$/' archivo
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
---------------------- equipo -----------------------
```

Donde, si se encuentra el patrón, se hará la acción por default en `awk` que es imprimir el registro completo.

### Sobre la expresión regular.

La explicación de esa expresión regular es que "^[-]+" espera que el patrón inicie (^) con una repetición de más de un caracter "-" ([-]+), después con un espacio ([[:space:]]) y luego que continue la palabra "equipo" y después se repita de la misma manera ([[:space:]] y [-]+) pero que finalice con ese patrón ($)

Ahora, si sólo quieres que esté la palabra "equipo", sin importar lo que tenga antes o después, puedes quitar los meta caracteres y dejar sólo los comandos con la palabra equipo.

```
$ sed '/equipo/p' archivo
$ grep 'equipo' archivo
$ awk '/equipo/' archivo
```